# matplotlib data points plotted but no line between them?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a line chart with multiple data sets on the same axes, so the markers show up but not the line. I really can't see what I am doing wrong. Can someone put another set of eyes on this, please?

Here is the data print:

```
looking at 2015-08-05 83.0 AA attribs sector= Materials shape= o kolor= b x = 2015-08-05 y =  83.0
looking at 2015-08-06 50.0 AA attribs sector= Materials shape= o kolor= b x = 2015-08-06 y =  50.0
looking at 2015-08-07 42.0 AA attribs sector= Materials shape= o kolor= b x = 2015-08-07 y =  42.0
looking at 2015-08-10 75.0 AA attribs sector= Materials shape= o kolor= b x = 2015-08-10 y =  75.0
```

Here is the code segment:

```
for count, symb in enumerate(my_symbols):
   sector = sector_format[str(sym_sect[symb])][0]
   shape = sector_format[str(sym_sect[symb])][1]
   kolor = sector_format[str(sym_sect[symb])][2]
   x = my_dates[count]
   y = rank_2010[count]
   print("looking at",x,y,symb,"attribs",
         "sector=",sector,
         "shape=",shape,
         "kolor=",kolor,
         "x =",x,
         "y = ",y)

  if symb == 'AA' or symb == "AAPL":
     plt.plot(x,y,lw=5,color=kolor,linestyle='solid',marker=shape)

plt.title('hv 20 to 10 ranks')
plt.xlabel('dates')
plt.ylabel('symbol ranks')
plt.show()
```

[image: this is what is been plotted right now]

Comment: It'd be a lot easier if we could've gotten non-string formatted data (i.e. in a copy-pastable list perhaps). What I think is happening is that you're plotting every point as a different line and then manually setting them all to the same markers and shapes. Turn on the legend and you'll probably see 4 different groups of data in it. What you want to do is put the data in 2 lists `x, y` and send those lists to `plt.plot` outside the `for` loop.

Comment: Hey there ljetibo  but the data set is a little tricky. Basically I have 1000 days of data for 100 symbols. I split the days into one list  ( my_dates[] which is the x axis) and another list is the rank data ( rank_2010[]) which is the y axis.) now for the tricky bit. Each rank_2010 has a symbol which is used to lookup a sector ( in this case symbol = AA which is sector "materials") a sector has a set of attributes that are applied to a line so I want to end up with all 100 symbols plotted using their relevant sector format AND when I point at a line I get the symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are calling `plot` multiple times wanting it to collect the data you give it into one set. That's not how `plot` works. You need to form a data set (one "line" in your plot) and pass that to `plot`. Something along the lines of:

```
x_list = []
y_list = []

for count, symb in enumerate(my_symbols):
   sector = sector_format[str(sym_sect[symb])][0]
   shape = sector_format[str(sym_sect[symb])][1]
   kolor = sector_format[str(sym_sect[symb])][2]
   x = my_dates[count]
   y = rank_2010[count]
   print("looking at",x,y,symb,"attribs",
         "sector=",sector,
         "shape=",shape,
         "kolor=",kolor,
         "x =",x,
         "y = ",y)

  if symb == 'AA' or symb == "AAPL":
      x_list.append(x)
      y_list.append(y)

plt.plot(x_list,y_list,lw=5,color=kolor,linestyle='solid',marker=shape)

plt.title('hv 20 to 10 ranks')
plt.xlabel('dates')
plt.ylabel('symbol ranks')
plt.show()
```

This may not be exactly what you want. I'm unclear on what you're trying to do with different colors and marks, so you may have to modify it. However, I think it should get you in the right direction at least.

Comment: Hey CrazyCasta sorry I didn't read this before responding to ljetibo where I clear up why this is a little more complex than it appears. I will certainly try your approach and thank you for looking at this.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt BUT no luck.  If it were just plotting x and y I would be a happy bunny but I have to loop through 1000 days each contains a rank for a stock. The rank is the y axis the date is the x axis which gives me the first point. the stock symbol gives me the sector which determines the line attribs. So I sort the file into symbol order which already are in date order. I loop through all the days for each symbol plotting ( or not in my case :-)) the "line" . Thanks for the attempt but I had tried it and did so again using your code no luck

Comment: Does my code at least plot lines? I mean, it's not still just plotting points, right?

Comment: Also, to be clear, are you asking for one line per sector then?

Comment: Hey CrazyCasta sorry NO lines at all and NOPE it's waaayyyy worse than just a line per sector.  The data is for each DAY there are 100 symbols each has a rank 1 to 100. SO for each day ( x axis) there are 100 points on the Y axis ( rank). NOW as 100 shapes would look messy I have to group each stock into it's sector ( there are 7 sectors) and plot the point as that symbol. SO NOW I move onto the next day and repeat the process joining the points from yesterday to today. AND I need to label the line with the stock symbol. That's why I am having a hard time here. Any ideas?

Comment: Oops, my bad. Try now. I had x,y in plot instead of x_list,y_list.

Comment: It sounds like what you want to do is collect the data in separate lists for each symbol, then plot each one of those lists with a separate call to plt.plot where you lookup the color and marker based on the stock's symbol.

Comment: Hey CrazyCasta I made the mod ( I didn't spot it either sorry) and I now see a line. The data is wrong BUT I am MUCH close thanks to you. Thanks so much you are a star!!!